# Cambiar el Foreground de una celda en especifica dentro de un Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tengo una lista de IPs y cada una de esas IPs se tienen que comparar con las que tengo en la base de datos, si las IPs coinciden se agregara una nueva fila PERO la celda IP se pondra con el foreground color verde. Alguien tiene alguna idea? Yo he tratado de hacerlo con Triggers y solo funcionan con valos preestablecidos, pero como cada IP es diferente y no se cual vendra no puedo hacerlo de esa forma.

Comment: Todas las celdas de esa columna? o solo algunas?

Comment: Creo que un esquema sería de bastante ayuda, así un ejemplo mínimo verificable para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte de mejor manera.

Comment: @Leodev solo una celda de esa columna, la IP que coincide con la de la base de datos debe tornarse verde.

Comment: Tienes varias opciones. Puedes usar un valueconverter, o simplemente en el viewmodel crea un bool que pongas a true o false dependiendo de si está o no en la base de datos, y usa ese valor como trigger para el color.

Comment: Las columnas del DataGrid se autogeneran? o las definirás en XAML manualmente? porque la respuesta será diferente, sé como hacerlo, pero dime eso para hacer la respuesta más corta. No estoy en casa, pero llegando al PC te publicaré como se hace lo que pides, si nadie más responde antes. Como recomendación: Es importante que des toda la información posible para estas preguntas, será más fácil que obtengas una respuesta si pones código y detalles.

Comment: @Leodev Las columnas se autogeneran; La proxima vez agrego codigo y tratare de explicar mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Yap.. Usas MVVM? Llenas el DataGrid con una lista de objetos? o es una consulta SQL plana? Te contesto enseguida que me lo aclares (disculpa tanta pregunta pero esto de los datagrids tiene su ciencia).

Comment: una lista de objetos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la forma, lo que hice fue crear un otro constructor mas a mi clase para que cuando haya una coincidencia su valor sea true.

```
class Data{
 public string ip{ get; set;}
 public string ips { get; set; }
}
```

Luego de eso hice que un trigger evaluara si es true o false.

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP" Binding="{Binding ip}"  Width="30*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ips}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding hosts}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Como veran, si `ips` es false el texto sera de color `Crimson` y si es true su color sera `DodgerBlue`